# Weird sans-serif and serif font in IE9 and IE10

Tags: css, fonts, internet-explorer-9

I am working on my portfolio website:

http://timdream.org/

Everything checks out in Firefox and Chrome, but when I open it up on IE9 and IE10, the text of the entire page (apart from the web font header and the "I realise dreams" phrase) was being assigned a weird unknown font.

I've double checked all the code, where in HTML I got

```
<html lang="en">
```

and in CSS I got

```
body {
    font: 12px/16px serif
}
```

supposedly the above should tell to render the page in default Latin-based serif font, which is Times New Roman had user not change it.

What happened exactly?

Note: source code available for testing at https://github.com/timdream/timdream.github.com . Remove appCache manifest to prevent enabling it in Chrome when testing.

**Update:** screenshot in IE9 below.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: could you post a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: If you want Times New Roman, why not just specify it?

Comment: @sethobrien Because I don't want Times New Roman to show up on a Mac, which comes with a better default serif font.

Comment: why not specify the mac font, times new roman, then serif?

Comment: @DavidNguyen Then I would have to investigate better serif font on various Linux distro; The reason why I stuck with generic font names is because I would like to leave the browsers/OS to figure out the best Latin-based font for me, something IE9 failed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font in the screenshot is Batang, and it appears because it is what the generic font name `serif` is mapped to in IE (in several versions).

For some more notes on this, see
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/34399/unknown-css-font-family-oddity-with-ie7-10-on-windows-vista-7-8

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that your web server is including a Content-Language HTTP response that is overriding your `lang="en"`?

Comment: No, there wasn't any `Content-Language`. I can tell by running `wget -q --save-headers http://timdream.org/ -O - | less`